# $row variable in php

Tags: php, mysqli

what is the $row variable in php? and whats the duty of $row variable in php?

**Code :-**

```
function getCats() {

global $con;

$get_cats = "select * from categories";  //select from database

$run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);  //

while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

$cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
$cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

echo"<li><a href='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";

}

}
```

Comment: It's a normal variable.

Comment: I don't see any **$row** variable in your code

Answer (score 0):

It is just a variable, it can be anything, like $line etc.
In your case, variable $row_cats is being used to fetch data from database.

Answer (score 0):

**$row** is just a name of a variable.

When you are using *mysqli_fetch_array*, you can get rows from resource you get from MySQL like

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    /* do_something */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you can use any name of variable.. then is no special name for special variable types, but for standardization of code **you have to use variable name with good naming convention**.

I noticed in your code, so I suggesting you some points regarding variable naming conventions.

1. As per your code `$get_cats` is storing query string you can keep name of that variable `$category_query` or only `$query`.
2. $run_cates in this variable you are storing result reference of category query which is return from `mysqli_query()`, so meaning full name of that variable is `$category_result` or only `$result`.
3. $row_cats in while loop, `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns data of one row of result so better name is `$category_row` or `$row` only